# My bot doesn't reply to tweets that are replies to other tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, reply

I created a twitter bot, but it only replies to specific tweets. For example, if i tweet anything and then reply to this tweet tagging the bot, the bot will reply. But if i tweet a regular tweeting or reply to another account that is not myself, the bot will simply not reply. Help please!

```
import tweepy
import time

api_key = 'API KEY'
api_secret = 'API SECRET'
bearer_token = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
access_token = 'ACCESS TOKEN'
access_secret = 'ACCESS SECRET'

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_secret)

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

client_id = client.get_me().data.id

message = 'sexo'

while True:
response = client.get_users_mentions(client_id)

    if response.data != None:
        for tweet in response.data:
            try:
                client.create_tweet(in_reply_to_tweet_id=tweet.id, text = message)
            except:
                pass
    
    time.sleep(3)
```

I was expecting the bot to reply to every single tweet that mentions him

Comment: Remove the try/except and [edit] the question to include full details of any error that occurs.

Comment: @snakecharmerb i actually couldn't find another way to do this without try and except. I'm a beginner in python (actually studying it for 3 months lol), so that's the only way that it makes sense to me

Comment: It's likely that some replies are missing because `client.create_tweet` errors out.  But unless you tell us what the errors are (by removing the try/except and telling us happens) we can't help.